# Qt: Get ASCII Code From QChar

Tags: qt, qchar

I need to get the ASCII code from a `QChar`.

In Qt 5.2 `QChar::ToAscii` has been removed.

Here is my code. How can I get the ASCII code?

```
QString data;
int key;
key = data.at(i);
```

Comment: Strange, seems that you had been able to provide an answer on your own, by casting the extracted char to an integer. This should accomplish your task without passing through the toAscii() function, in fact. Can you provide a deeper explanation about the problem you're facing, with that code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use:

```
char QChar::toLatin1() const
```

From the doc:

> Returns the Latin-1 character equivalent to the QChar, or 0. This is mainly useful for non-internationalized software.

From a Qt5.0 version

```
char QChar::toAscii() const
```

> This function is deprecated.
>   Returns the Latin-1 character value of the QChar, or 0 if the character is not representable.

Example

```
QString test("test");
QChar c = test.at(0);
int v_latin = c.toLatin1();
int v_ascii = c.toAscii();
qDebug() << v_latin << " " << v_ascii;
```

Output:

```
116   116
```

Comment: I am looking ascii code from `×` multiply sign and the QChar store a negative value = -41. When I look into the ascii table the value for it sign is 158, why do I get this negative value?